# Using gDEBugger with Qt OpenGL application

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, opengl

I'm trying to use gDEBugger to debug my OpenGL application, but the problem is that when I use normal GLFW libraries, gDEBugger runs the program and stops at specified breakpoints, but when I use Qt's `QOpenGLWidget`, although I'm calling native OpenGL API calls, when I try to step through the program, it seems that gDEBugger runs the program and the program exits, without any stop on breakpoints.

Does anybody know how to use gDEBugger to step through OpenGL code in Qt? Are there other debugger tools available I can use?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems using Nvidia Nsight and QOpenGLWidget. In nsight I'd only see the draw calls of QOpenGLWidget and not my own.

The problem for me was that I was setting the default QSurfaceFormat explicitly myself to the desired OpenGL version.

When I commented it out and not longer set that, it worked fine. And I could now see both contexts, mine and the one used by the qopenglwidget.

Not sure why this happens. Probably worth looking into the source to see how the widget renders to texture and then calls your rendering functions.

Let me know if it works for u?

Comment: Actually, I'm not using any Qt wrappers for OpenGL and all my calls are direct calls to OpenGL native functions. I'm not sure if you were doing the same, but because of this fact, I expected to be able to use the tool

Comment: Same for me. There is a sublte difference between QGLWidget and QOpenGLWidget. The former is a native window that uses just the raw gl calls that you provide. The later is totally draw using openGL, it takes your raw GL calls, renders them to an Texture, then it renders the rest of the UI, and it mushes them together. I suspect that it uses some non-core functions (maybe) and the debugger is getting confused. What card are you running?

Comment: I have an Nvidia card and integrated Intel card on my laptop. I think by default, it's going to use the integrated Intel one

Comment: Use nvidias nsight to have a look at your draw calls. If you're on a recent laptop you can use Nvidia settings to switch between them. Both Windows and Linux offer this https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition using a debugger with qopenglwidget isn't as straight forward as with other window toolkits. I dont always have success and sometimes the debugger crashes.

Comment: I have downloaded Nsight, but when I try to run the monitor (or using the plugin in visual studio, it gives a **CommunicationException** error. Do you know what's happening here?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I solved that issue, but I have this one:

I have installed Nsight, but when I try to run the program using their graphic debugger, it doesn't load Qt dependencies (DLLs) the same as the situation where I would run it normally from Visual Studio. Do you have any idea what I can do?
It should read the values defined in my project's **Debugging/Environment** settings, but apparently it's not!

Comment: Simplest is to put the Qt bin directory in your path(where all the Qtxxx. Dll) are and it'll work nicely.

Comment: Thanks, is there a tutorial for this thing? Because I managed to make it work, but I have no idea how to see anything with it!

Comment: There should be some online documents. The basic flow is to start 'graphics debugging'. Your application will run the Nvidia HUD overlay. Then go back into VS and the Nvidia menu and select 'pause and capture frame', it'll capture the frame and open some windows in VS and show your frame profiled. One thing to note is that your app will need to render a frame after you select the capture feature.

Comment: When I run my application (using 'start graphics debugging'), the 'pause and capture frame' is disabled. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: Not sure to be honest, You'll need to google why. Maybe either you are using an unsupported graphics API, or it hasn't been loaded? Some wild guesses.

Comment: Thank you anyway for all your replies; I'll keep you updated in case I manage to make it work

Comment: If you can get on a Linux box, Nvidia havd a different tool called the OpenGL Graphics debugger for Linux. Maybe try that?if you can get on an amd box, their perf studio software is nice. I liked it a little better